# fopen: is it good idea to leave open, or use buffer?

Tags: c++, c, file, io

So I have many log files that I need to write to. They are created when program begins, and they save to file when program closes.

I was wondering if it is better to do:

fopen() at start of program, then close the files when program ends - I would just write to the files when needed. Will anything (such as other file io) be slowed down with these files being still "open" ?

OR

I save what needs to be written into a buffer, and then open file, write from buffer, close file when program ends. I imagine this would be faster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, `fopen(3) + fwrite(3) + fclose(3)` *is* a buffered I/O package, so another layer of buffering on top of it might just slow things down.

In any case, go for a simple and correct program. If it seems to run slowly, profile it, and then optimize based on evidence and not guesses.

Comment: +1, also writing to some buffer while the program runs doesn't necessarily mean it will get written when a crash occurs.  Better to have as much on it on disk as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

1. Big number of opened files shouldn't slow down anything
2. Writing to file will be buffered anyway

So you can leave those files opened, but do not forget to check the limit of opened files in your OS.

Comment: When discussing buffered and unbuffered I/O, the terms almost always refer to what a user program hands off to the kernel, not something that the kernel does or doesn't do. In most contexts, it is incorrect to say something *"will be buffered by the kernel".* If you mean, *"by the C runtime library",* then yes, I agree.

Comment: I suppose it could also depends of the OS

Comment: Ah, thank you. I knew C++'s io was buffered - wasn't sure on C's. Any place where I can read up on basic IO and good practices (and fastest way to do things)?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the point of log files is being able to figure out what happened when/if your program runs into a problem. Quite a few people also do log file analysis in (near) real-time.  Your second scenario doesn't work for either of these.

I'd start with the first approach, but with a high-enough level interface that you could switch to the second if you really needed to. I wouldn't view that switch as a major benefit of the high-level interface though -- the real benefit would normally be keeping the rest of the code a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to buffer log messages in your program and write them out on exit. Simply write them as they're generated using `fprintf`. The `stdio` system will take care of the buffering for you. Of course this means opening the file (with `fopen`) from the beginning and keeping it open.

Answer (score 1):

For log files, you will probably want a functional interface that flushes the data to disk after each complete message, so that if the program crashes (it *has* been known to happen), the log information is safe.  Leaving stuff in standard I/O buffers means excavating the data from a core dump - which is less satisfactory than having the information on disk safely.

Other I/O really won't be affected by holding one - or even a few - log files open.  You lose a few file descriptors, perhaps, but that is not often a serious problem.  When it is a problem, you use one file descriptor for one log file - and you keep it open so you can log information.  You might elect to map `stderr` to the log file, leaving that as the file descriptor that's in use.

Comment: Do you happen to have any examples of good log systems? Preferably bare-bones ones?

Comment: @Pepe: One option - not necessarily minimal - is [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/).  I've not used it.  I usually use my own `stderr` package - available readily from the [IIUG Software Archive](http://www.iiug.org/software) as part of the program SQLCMD - or you can contact me directly (see my profile).

Answer (score 1):

It's been mentioned that the FILE* returned by fopen is already buffered. For logging, you should probably also look into using the setbuf() or setvbuf() functions to change the buffering behavior of the FILE*.

In particular, you might want to set the buffering mode to line-at-a-time, so the log file is flushed automatically after each line is written. You can also specify the size of the buffer to use.

Comment: Good point but by default fopen opens files in line mode on most Unixes. On Windows/DOS world you had to open the file in text mode (`fopen("file.txt", "wt")` to enable that behaviour without `setbuv`.