# Should I leave a QFile (or fstream) open?

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, io, fstream

I usually use two methods to write to files, either with Qt's QFile or STL's fstream.

I have a long-running (several minutes) simulation which logs data to a file. Performance-wise and design-wise, is it a good idea to:

1. Keep it open the whole time
2. Close and open on every write
3. Somewhere in-between (1) and (2)

Several question on here address this issue (for [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867468/should-i-keep-a-file-open-or-should-i-open-and-close-often), for [fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835359/fopen-is-it-good-idea-to-leave-open-or-use-buffer)), but I didn't see any discussion of QFile and fstream. The previous answers suggest to keep it open (option 1). Is this still the cast for QFile and fstream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wise, it would definitely be better to keep it open for the life of the application, just because less work opening and closing files means less time spent doing things that don't move the application closer to completion, which will slow the program down. As for design, just make sure to close the file before the application terminates.

QFile and fstream probably use fopen, fwrite etc under the hood (although it is of course implementation dependent). So I would bet that anything applying to `FILE*`s would apply to QFiles and fstreams.

Answer (score 1):

This may be dependent on your libc implementation but fstream is generally uses memory-mapped files. These are generally very efficient, and only main memory or swap when a page of data is written to.

If you are running a 32-bit system and these files are very large or very numerous then you could have issues with exhausting the virtual address space (on windows ~2GB might cause such problems). Seeing as you are simply logging this seems quite unlikely.

But simply closing the files might make it worse in that case because then the virtual address space could become fragmented.

I would advise that it is best to leave the files open at all times unless you think you will run into the issues above. If you are memory constrained then flushing the data will reduce the physical memory requirements.

Comment: Where did you get this information?  I think you a bit confused.

Comment: Is there anything here you have a problem with specifically?